# Зачем обязать использовать try catch?

Tags: java, исключения

```
try {
    d = (Date)super.clone();
    if (cdate != null) {
        d.cdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) cdate.clone();
    }
} catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {} // Won't happen
```

*java.util.Date:280*

Если из этого вырезать `try { } catch () {}`, то код просто не скомпилируется. А почему? Почему не разрешить писать без `try-catch`, если всё равно `// Won't happen`  ? Т.е.:

```
d = (Date)super.clone();
if (cdate != null) {
     d.cdate = (BaseCalendar.Date) cdate.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле, разработчики jdk просто переусердствовали с обилием checked exceptions, из-за чего во многих местах приходится писать пустые, ничего не значащие try-catch обработчики.

Comment: Да уж, и во многих случаях "уязвимый" по мнению Java код просто не может быть не обернут в try->catch. Иначе код не компилируется. Безопасная, такая безопасная Java :)

Comment: @0xFFh LOLWUT? Какой еще уязвимый код? Это просто статическая проверка по `throws`-декларации.

Answer (score 2):

Такой подход обусловлен тем, что таким образом обеспечивается большая надёжность: в джаве невозможно забыть обработать исключение, можно только "забить" на него, написав пустой обработчик.
Если нет нужды обрабатывать исключение в данном методе, можно пробросить исключение на более верхний уровен, написав

```
void foo() throws OloloException{
    //Код
}
```

Comment: >  в джаве невозможно забыть обработать исключение,

Не совсем так, есть же unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

в вашем вопросе по сути 2 вопроса:

> Почему не разрешить писать без try-catch

Потому что метод `clone` в классе `Date` имеет сигнатуру:

```
public Object clone()
```

класс Date наследуется напрямую от `Object` а поэтому вызов `super.clone();` вызывает метод класса `Object` который имеет сигнатуру:

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

который собственно и выбрасывает `CloneNotSupportedException` который относится к типу `checked exceptions` и должен быть обработан в теле данного метода. Другими словами разработчики языка тоже обязаны следовать его стандартам.

А сейчас вторая часть вопроса:

> всё равно // Won't happen ?

Почему "won't happen" потому что класс `Date` имплементирует интерфейс `Clonable` а значит функционал метода `clone` обьявленного в классе `Object` должен отработать нормально, и ошибку не выбрасывать.

p.s. **short summary**: если вы используете метод который выбрасывает `checked exception` вы обязаны добавить обработку этой ошибки не зависимо от того будет он выброшен или нет. Или же вы должны добавить эту ошибку в сигнатуру своего метода тогда о ней должен позаботится тот кто будет его использовать

Answer (score -8):

вам никто не запрещает писать без *try-catch*.

просто не пользуйтесь чужими классами, интерфейсами. напишите своих

ну или так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {}
```